# UIViewController no longer has members topViewController or viewControllers in XCode 7

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

After updating to XCode 7 and converting my project to the latest Swift 2 syntax, there is one error I cannot seem to fix. I have a segue to a navigation controller and need to pass data to the top view controller in its stack. The following has always worked until now:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController.viewControllers[0] as! MYViewController
    // OR let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController.topViewController as! MYViewController
    // ...
}
```

But now the compiler gives error:

`Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'viewControllers'`
or
`Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'topViewController'`

I do not see how else to access the view controller(s) on the stack. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `as! UINavigationController` after `segue.destinationViewController` so that to cast to `UINavigationController` class type.

```
let destinationVC = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).viewControllers[0] as! MYViewController
```

Or

```
let destinationVC = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! MYViewController
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated in Swift 3 (Xcode 8) to

```
let dvc = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).viewControllers[0] as! MyViewController
```

or `viewControllers[0]` can be replace with `topViewController`